# Python SystemError when using the C API PyRun_String

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to run, in a C++ program, some python file that is actually included in the C++ code as a `std::string` called `command`.

I have been successful using `PyRun_SimpleString(command.c_str())`, but this prevents getting exception information.

I now try the following instead:

```
PyObject* result = PyRun_String(command.c_str(), Py_file_input, PyEval_GetGlobals(), PyEval_GetLocals());
```

However, this throws:

```
SystemError: frame does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE:

I tried to split the process into compile+eval using the following:

```
PyObject* code = Py_CompileString(command.c_str(), filename.c_str(), Py_file_input);
PyObject* result = PyEval_EvalCode(code, PyEval_GetGlobals(), PyEval_GetLocals());
```

Now, the error is different:

```
SystemError: PyEval_EvalCodeEx: NULL globals
```

This is maybe more explanatory, as it says in the [C API doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/reflection.html#c.PyEval_GetGlobals)::

> Return a dictionary of the global variables in the current execution frame, or NULL if no frame is currently executing.

I am not sure I understand what a frame is.

Comment: Can you please post the command string?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o all commands fail. I tried, for instance, "import math" or "print(1)"

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. I probably have not understood when a frame is exectuting or not, but it turns out that just after launching the interpreter, no frames are running. That's why `PyEval_GetGlobals()` and `PyEval_GetLocals()` were returning `NULL` and caused errors later.

Instead, the namespace of the default module `__main__` should be used as both globals and locals namespaces:

```
PyObject* d = PyModule_GetDict(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"));
PyObject* result = PyRun_String(command.c_str(), Py_file_input, d, d);
Py_DECREF(result);
```